# Issue with publishing and subscribing product detail attributes in meteor / iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor, controller, router

I am having trouble with properly publishing, subscribing, and displaying a products detail page. I have a collection of Products with an attribute called productCode. Here is my Products collection:

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
```

Here is my publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish('tireDetails'), function(_id) {
return {
    products: Products.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
};
};
```

Here is my controller:

```
tireDetailsController = RouteController.extend({
waitOn: function () { 
    Meteor.subscribe('tireDetails');
},
action: function() {
    this.render('tireDetails');
}

});
```

My router.js:

```
Router.route('/products/tires/:_id', {name: 'tireDetails', controller: 'tireDetailsController'});
```

And here is my template:

```
<template name="tireDetails">
  {{#with products}}
      <p>{{productCode}}</p>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

I think the way that I am publishing my products is wrong. Furthermore, I typed in the browser console:

Products.findOne();

Which returned undefined... please help!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishers need to return a cursor or an array of cursors. `findOne` returns a document. Furthermore, your publisher does not have access to `this.params._id`. Try something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('tireDetails', function(id) {
  return Products.find(id);
});
```

and your `waitOn` should look like:

```
waitOn: function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('tireDetails', this.params._id);
}
```

---

In order to have the `product` rendered to your template you could add a [data](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-with-data) parameter to your controller:

```
data: function() {
  return {product: Products.findOne(this.params._id})};
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<template name="tireDetails">
  <p>{{product.productCode}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks David. Question though - the 'this.params._id' in the subscribe method gets passed into the 'id' in the publish function, correct?

Comment: Also, now Products.findOne(); in the browser console returns the correct data. However, the data is still not showing up on the template...

Comment: Yes, the id is passed to the publlisher as the 2nd argument in the subscribe. See the updated answer on how to get the data into the template.